# Set delegate of objects to nil which are assigned to self in cellforrowatindexpath

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, delegates

I have a custom control say `CustomControl` in my application. This control is used in each of the custom `UITableViewCell` I have used in the tableview of my View Controller.

On some event I want to notify the state of my CustomControl to my View Controller. So I have created  Protocol for CustomControl and as I want View Controller to notify, so I have assigned the `customCell.customControl.delegate = self;` in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Now I want to set this delegate to nil for all the custom cells in the `dealloc` of my view controller. Can anyone tell how can I do this?

Comment: and ... what the problem?

Comment: and for what reason do you whant to set this delegate to nil, do you retain your delegate object in CustomControl ?

Comment: as the delegates are not being set to nil, when I use the same custom cells in another view controller the previous view control is receiving the delegate call too which is causing problems.

Comment: @PavelKatunin as far as I know we can't retain delegates.

Comment: Yes, i just wondered for what reason do you want to set it to nil.

Comment: @AmmadHussain This doesn't make sense. If you create new instances of the custom controls in another view controller, how can the delegates be set to the other view controller?

Comment: Do you use same cells objects in other view controller?

Comment: Yes, the custom cell is being used in multiple view controllers and when i move from one view controller to another view controller, the previous view controller is still receiving the delegate calls because I am not able to set there delegates nil in the previous controller.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you always set the delegate of your custom control in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, you could try something like this in your CustomCell class:

```
- (void)prepareForReuse
{
    [super prepareForReuse];
    self.myCustomControl.delegate = nil;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It gave me a rather easy idea, just setting the delegate of custom control nil in custom cell's dealloc method.